# QtCreator - start external tool in an interactive bash

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, settings, qt-creator

A while ago I discovered that you can make QtCreator call external tools directly from within the IDE and pass various arguments to those via the **Tool->External**. I find this pretty convenient however I'm currently struggling with the issue of starting a **terminal-based** application in an interactive bash. I am using Lubuntu 12.04 with QtCreator 2.5.2.

Usually you can start a new interactive bash with a specific application running in it by writing something like

```
$ bash -i -c some_command
```

with -i being the argument for interactive mode and -c telling bash to read the string that follows as some command/commands.

The dialog for configuration of external tools in QtCreator has two fields that omho are important in my case - **Executable** and **Arguments**. The first one points at the tool that you want to launch and the second allows you to start it with a bunch of arguments. However this seems not to be working! I'm trying to add **htop** (an advanced terminal-based task manager) along with other useful tools. However following problem occurs when trying to use bash:

For

```
Executable: bash
Arguments: -i -c htop
```

I get

> Starting external tool '/bin/bash' -i -c htop
>
> bash: no job control in this shell
>
> Error opening terminal: unknown.
>
> '/bin/bash' finished

For

```
Executable: bash
Arguments: htop
```

> Starting external tool '/bin/bash' htop
>
> /usr/bin/htop: /usr/bin/htop: cannot execute binary file
>
> '/bin/bash' finished

which is perfectly normal as an error message since the **-c** argument is exactly what is needed to start htop in a new bash.

The funny thing is that using **xterm** (which is also the default external terminal for QtCreator (even though I didn't have it on my system at first -_-) works like a charm. If I use the following settings for my htop-tool

```
Executable: xterm
Arguments: -e htop
```

it opens a perfectly working, interactive htop in an external window running **xterm**.

Does anyone have any idea how to replace xterm with bash or is it just that I'm missing something? I've set my bash pretty nicely (even if I didn't the default fonts and font size along with the absence of tabs in xterm should be a big enough reason not to use it unless one wants to configure it manually) and really want to use it. I've also tried looking at the documentation of QtCreator and the external tool XML files but was unable to find enough information to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[xterm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm) is a terminal emulator while [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) is a shell. You need a terminal emulator to run a shell or other text-based applications interactively in a graphical environment.

It sounds like you have a shortcut to a predefined terminal emulator starting Bash. I would suggest finding out which terminal emulator that is (maybe [LXTerminal](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXTerminal)?) and using that terminal emulator to run `htop`:

```
Executable: LXTerminal
Arguments: -e htop
```

Read about the `-e` option in the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/lxterminal.1.html) (your version's documentation may vary).

Comment: That is indeed the solution. I forgot about the nature of xterm, lxterminal (lower case!) etc. It's working as expected. Thanks a lot!